# Load & Swoop Image Adds With Auto Refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I'm looking to add a section for Sponsors and I would like it to load a random sponsor image and then replace it after like 2 seconds with another sponsors image and continue to swoop out.

Could someone tell me how to do this, I would think it's a Jquery Thing?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the url to the images in an array as below

```
var images = [];
var currentImage= 0;
images[0] = "image1.jpg";
images[1] = "image2.jpg";
images[2] = "image3.jpg";
```

Then use the following jQuery snipped to refresh the images every few seconds which can be customized

```
function changeImage() {
currentImage++;
if(currentImage > 2) currentImage = 0;

$('img').fadeOut(100,function() {
    $('img').attr('src',images[currentImage]);
    $('img').fadeIn(100);
});


setTimeout(changeImage, 2000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(changeImage, 2000);        
});
```

You can look at the demo on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ewupey/1)

Comment: Thank's I must be doing something wrong. Please see http://www.justvibe.co.uk/listen-now.php

Comment: You should put javascipt within `<script></script>` tags

Comment: Also you should put an `<img>` tag with a default image, since you have many images on your site, it is better to associate a `id` with it, have the look at the full code on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ewupey/2/edit), I have modified a little so you can use directly

Comment: I have done that but its still not working, Any other thing im doing wrong?

Comment: YOu forgot the opening `<script>` after `<h3>` tag

Comment: You should look at the [code](http://jsbin.com/ewupey/2/edit) then you will understand what you are missing.

Comment: I've updated the code to make it faster and more easily extendable: http://jsbin.com/ewupey/5/edit

Comment: You aren't even copy pasting our code properly, Please look at http://jsbin.com/aceyax/1/edit, I have copied the sponsors `div` and implemented the image swap.

Comment: Thank you all is working and thank you for your time you have been great. I really appreciate it.